# Get files from S3 by case insensitive file names

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I am using the following C# code to get file from S3 storage-

```
public string GetFileContent(string bucketName, string fileKey)
{
        try
        {
            using (GetObjectResponse Response = _S3Client.GetObject(new GetObjectRequest()
            {
                BucketName = bucketName,
                Key = fileKey
            }))
            return GetS3FileInStringFormat(Response);
        }
        catch
        {

        }
}
```

But this code gives the file content only when the supplied file name is equals in case with the file stored in S3. Is there a way I can get the file content ignoring the cases? I can not modify existing files in the S3 buckets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon S3 filenames (`key`) are case-sensitive.

You must specify the key exactly as it appears in Amazon S3. If this is a problem, you could:

- Call [GetBucket](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/v2-RESTBucketGET.html) to retrieve a list of objects
- Loop through the list, trying to find the one that matches your case-insensitive name
- Call `GetObject` using the case-sensitive name